# Using Zend Framework 2 Tool / ZF2 Tool

Tags: zend-framework2

Apparently there is a version of [ZF Tool for ZF2](https://github.com/zendframework/ZFTool). 
The tool should handle the following:

- Module maintenance (installation, configuration, removal etc.)
- Inspection of application configuration.
- Deploying zf2 skeleton applications.

The problem is that the tools is itself installed as a module and the Usage described in the [Readme](https://github.com/zendframework/ZFTool/blob/master/README.md) does not provide "correct" details.

It mentions commands such as :

```
zf.php config [list]
```

but the zf.php command is not part of the tool and the doc does not provide information. Does anyone know if there is some dependency or other configurations that will make this tool useful?

Comment: It's indeed not written clearly, does this help: https://github.com/zendframework/ZFTool/issues/2 ?

Comment: And: https://github.com/zendframework/ZFTool/issues/5

Answer (score 1):

I don't know. What I can do, is offer an alternative tool:

https://github.com/ebanolopes/zf2-module-generator

Currently (v0.0.1), it only supports adding new modules to your project.